# is d3.axisBottom().tickFormat(""); an intended way to render an axis with ticks and without tick labels?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

found this issue today: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24716 
it concerns https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickFormat

apparently the argument for rejecting that PR is the following:

> The documented API in this case refers to:
>   ...sets the tick format function...
>   Staying away from undocumented source code behaviour in the TS definitions ensures that changes to internal implementations details of the source code do not break the definitions.

so I was just looking for some clarification on whether tickFormat can be used with a string value is

```
d3.axisBottom().tickFormat("");
```

an intended use case? to render an axis with ticks and without tick labels?

[image]

https://d3js.slack.com/archives/CGLMLCVEZ/p1574776972005200

Answer (score -1):

No, per the library author this is not the intended use case, this is a side effect.

In order to "deactivate" the tickmark labels, please simply use: `.tickFormat(() => '')` https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/24716#issuecomment-381427458

> No, that’s not intended. 
>   It’s more of a side-effect of the tick format function being passed directly to `selection.text`.
>   That said, it feels like a reasonable thing to support, albeit a little weird if the primary intent is to disable the tick text.
>   I feel like `tickFormat(null)` would be a cleaner way to do this, but the axis component currently treats null and undefined as the same, and so uses that to mean *“use the scale’s tick format”*.

[image]

https://d3js.slack.com/archives/CGLMLCVEZ/p1574783018008900